# Unable to filter for multiple features with JMESPath

Tags: python, jmespath

My data looks as follows. How come I am able to filter for one word using contains but not a list of words I wish to filter for?
both queries should produce the same output

```py
import jmespath

data = {'collection': {'items': {'word': 'ice-cube'}}}
jmespath.search(
  'values(collection)[?word!=null && contains([`cube`,`-`],word)]', 
  data
) # returns []
jmespath.search(
  'values(collection)[?word!=null && contains(word,`cube`)]', 
  data
) # works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the function `contains` is

```
boolean contains(array|string $subject, any $search)
```

So, when you are doing

```
contains([`cube`, `-`], word)
```

You are actually looking for the value of the property `word` in the array `` [`cube`, `-`] ``, and not the other way around, as you are doing it in

```
contains(word, `cube`)
```

Where you are indeed searching for `cube` in the value of the property `word`.

Furthermore:

> If `$subject` is an array, this function returns true if one of the elements in the array is equal to the provided `$search` value.

*<sup>Source: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains</sup>*

Which means you have to have exact match of what you are searching for in the subject, which is not what you are trying to do here.

---

For your requirement, you will have to construct the query with multiple contains:

```
collection.* | [?word && contains(word, `-`) && contains(word, `cube`)]
```

Which you can easily do, since you are doing your query with the Python library.

For example:

```py
import jmespath

data = {'collection': {'items': {'word': 'ice-cube'}}}
terms = {'cube', '-'}
contains = [f'contains(word, `{term}`)' for term in terms]
print(
  jmespath.search(
    f'collection.* | [?word && {" && ".join(contains)}]',
    data
  )
)
```

Would yield:

```py
[{'word': 'ice-cube'}]
```